# How do I win a strange game?

Tags: riddle, knowledge, anagram, video-games, movies

There's a phrase I need to remember, in order to be successful here.

In 1983, an important date, the SG-1000 was released by a company. If you can name that company, you're getting warm.

In fact, the name of the company, and what you're getting are, when combined, the origin of this phrase.

What's the phrase I need to remember, and where is it from?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The phrase is

> "A strange game. The only winning move is not to play."

The company that released the SG-1000 was

> Sega

> In fact, the name of the company, and what you're getting are, when combined, the origin of this phrase.

> We were just told we are getting WARM and so we anagram it with SEGA and get WarGames. The movie WarGames came out the same year as the SG-1000 and the phrase is the conclusion that the computer made after simulating nuclear war and tic-tac-toe.

Comment: That's correct, but you've managed to skip the anagram step. If nobody else gets it soon I'll accept this and start a bounty, otherwise I'll award it to a more complete answer. Does that seem fair?

Comment: @PuzzlingFerret I snuck an edit in which I believe covers that :)

Comment: Well done on that ninja edit